# Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build and run a simple project in Visual Studio 2017 (C++) in x64 using the Local Windows Debugger. However every time I try to run it using the debugger [I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMxv0.png)

This error doesn't show up when I change it from x64 to x86, but I need it to compile to x64. This has happened on both computers that I've tried it on, and seems to happen in every one of my projects. I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio already and nothing's changed. I've tried adding 'devenv.exe' as an exception to the Windows Firewall but no changes there either, even when I disabled the firewall completely. My antivirus isn't affecting it at all either: still happens when I disable it.

The application runs fine when I find it in the explorer and run it manually but then I don't have any debugging tools.

What am I doing wrong here, how do I make it build and run my project as x64?

Answer (score 8):

I get this error every time I have an active VPN connection. If you use a VPN, try disconnect and see if the error disappears.

Comment: I do use a VPN but there's no change when I turn it off, even after cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio after disconnecting your VPN.

Comment: Ah there we go, so I just need to keep my VPN off while developing it then. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed the problem seems to be from having a VPN connection. Is there a workaround though ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a VPN, the solution (assuming you have Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.7 or later) is as follows:

- Go to the Windows Start Menu and launch the “Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 Preview”
- Run: "%DevEnvDir%vsregedit.exe" set "%VSINSTALLDIR:~0,-1%" HKCU Debugger UseAnonymousPipes dword 1
- Restart VS if it is already running

That solution is from this [link to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/192928/unrecognized-error-occurred-in-the-windows-web-ser.html).